# How the Background Color Changes When Two Checkboxes are Checked

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I am working on a project. I want the background color to change when two checkboxes are checked. I tried the code below and it failed. I see the code  working when we delete it "edit-container2" but I dont want it. I want the Javascript code to work on a different div. (Different example, CSS Body background changes color.) How can I implement the solution?

Important: The code must be JavaScript. It's possible?

```js
$('.edit-container input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var container=$(this).parent('.edit-container');
    
    if(container.find('#a1:checked,#a2:checked').length==2)
        container.css('background','red');
    else
        container.css('background','');        
});
```

```css
.edit-container2 {width:100px; height:100px; }
.edit-container { width:200px; height:200px;}
```

```html
    <div class="edit-container">
      
          
        <div class="edit-container2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="a1" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="a2" />
        </div>
    
    </div>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3DPLd/17/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for wrong parent. First get .edit-container2 and then .edit-container.

Check this.

```js
$('.edit-container input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var container=$(this).parent('.edit-container2').parent('.edit-container');
    
    if(container.find('#a1:checked,#a2:checked').length==2)
        container.css('background','red');
    else
        container.css('background','');        
})
```

```css
.edit-container2 {width:100px; height:100px; background:green;}
.edit-container {background:blue; width:200px; height:200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="edit-container">
      
          
        <div class="edit-container2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="a1" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="a2" />
        </div>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I wonder how i can use localStorage on this code? I try everything but i could not.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than chaining an arbitrary amount of `.parent` methods, just use `.parentsUntil('.edit-container')`:

```js
$('.edit-container input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

    var container=$(this).parentsUntil('.edit-container'); // changed this line here
    
    if(container.find('#a1:checked,#a2:checked').length===2) { // use triple equals, not double
        container.css('background','red');
    } else {
        container.css('background','');        
    }
});
```

```css
.edit-container2 {width:100px; height:100px; }
.edit-container { width:200px; height:200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="edit-container">
      
          
        <div class="edit-container2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="a1" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="a2" />
        </div>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: It's work, thank you. I wonder how i can use localStorage on this code? i want  If  container.css('background','red') this activity to be saved.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your problem.

```
$('.edit-container2  input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  var container = $(this).parent().parent();

  if ($('#a1').is(':checked') && $('#a2').is(':checked')) {
    container.css('background', 'red')
  } else {
    container.css('background', '');
  }

});
```